# EXCEL: Format cells based on style of adjacent Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, pivot-table, cell

I'm trying to develop a report which is largely Pivot Table but with some adjacent cells for some other (non pivot-table-able) text values.

Each week the Pivot Table will be refreshed and rows with subheadings etc will move depending on the underlying data.

Every time this happens I have to manually format those adjacent cells to match the format of the pivot table.

Does anyone know how to make the cells inherit the Pivot Table's formatting 'style', please?

Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the not pivottable table area defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, in the Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim c As Range
    With Target.DataBodyRange
        Set c = .Columns(.Columns.Count)
    End With
    With c.End(xlToRight)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearFormats
        c.Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. Try it ;-)

Comment: No luck still for me :-( One of  _those_ days probably for me.

Comment: You know that changing style doesn't trigger a pivot update event - so try changing the style, then refreshing the pivot table

Comment: Try this [sample workbook](https://excel.solutions/copypivotformatright/): refresh the pivot table, and the format should be copied to the non-pivot range to the right.

Comment: Wow that's spot-on. I didn't mention that it's only that one column that needs to be re-formatted but I can adapt as necessary. Thanks Olly!

Comment: Not sure why won't work on mine but defo works with your shared book + 1

Answer (score 1):

You could create a named list of the main categories in the first column of the pivottable ({ACC, ACT, BAS, etc}). Presuming [ACC] is in cell A5, you use the following formula to conditionally format the non-pivot tabel:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A5,Named_List,0),0)>0
```

Comment: I like this approach too. Thank you MV - this is great.